# .NET Core 1.0 web publish tool does not copy some assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, web-publishing

After publishing my **.NET Core 1.0** web project via FileSystem option and start browsing application I`ve got this exception:

```
Can not find assembly file Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll at 'C:\***\refs,C:\***\'
                 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution.AppBaseCompilationAssemblyResolver.TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List`1 assemblies)
                 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution.CompositeCompilationAssemblyResolver.TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List`1 assemblies)
                 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
                 at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__16`2.MoveNext()
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.GetCompilationReferences()
                 at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.get_CompilationReferences()
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo fileInfo, String compilationContent)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo file)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.CreateCacheEntry(String relativePath, String normalizedPath, Func`2 compile)
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.GetOrAdd(String relativePath, Func`2 compile)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, String pageName, Boolean isMainPage)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultFilterAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAllResultFiltersAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResourceFilterAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

My project.json:

```
      {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },    
        "Microsoft.Extensions.CompilationAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-20221",
        "Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-20221",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.0.0",
        "JetBrains.Annotations": "10.1.5",
        "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final-2016-05-21",
        "Kendo.Mvc": "2016.2.630"
      },

      "tools": {
        "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.1.258",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "imports": [
            "netstandard1.6"
          ]
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "imports": [
            "netstandard1.6"
          ]
        },
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "imports": [
            "netstandard1.6"
          ]
        },
        "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "imports": [
            "netstandard1.6"
          ]
        },
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "imports": [
            "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81",
            "netstandard1.6"
          ]
        }
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "net461": { }
      },

      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
      },

      "publishOptions": {
        "include": [
          "wwwroot",
          "Views",
          "Areas/**/Views",
          "appsettings.json",
          "appsettings.Production.json",
          "nlog.config",
          "web.config"
        ]
      },

      "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
        "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
      }
    }
```

I discovered that publish tool does not copy some assemblies:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.dll
Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Core.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.dll
```

and more.

Can anybody help me fix publishing?

Comment: please post your project.json

Comment: I have added project.json into question

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core. Use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] and/or [tag:asp.net-core] tags instead and your question is more likely to be found by people who can help you with the issue